# How to get installed app details(icons,name,version) Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, native

Hi I am trying to achieve particular feature which will return the installed applications details like app name, icon(icon should be url/base64) and version. I am able to get application package name  using the following code. Can you any one update the following code.

```
private List<String> getNonSystemApps() {
    List<PackageInfo> packages = this.getReactApplicationContext()
        .getPackageManager()
        .getInstalledPackages(0);

    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final PackageInfo p: packages) {
        if ((p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
            ret.add(p.packageName);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dim, but I can' t figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: @KevinBoone I am working on react native application, and i am creating a custom component in java which will return all the installed application from android. The response should include app name version and app icon location url/base 64 url. The above code is working fine but i am only getting application package name. I am very week in android java.

Comment: If you've got a package name, then you can get an `ApplicationInfo` using `PackageManager.getApplicationInfo()`. You can get a reference to the `PackageManager` using `Context.getPackageManager()`. Then you can get the icon from `ApplicationInfo.loadIcon (packageManager)`.